# function in models is unrecognizable

Tags: django, django-models

I trying extend existed models so I added 'thumbnails' in to it. Unfortunately function related to this is not recognized and django console gives me:

```
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=_get_upload_image, blank=True, null=True)
NameError: name '_get_upload_image' is not defined
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

Django 1.6.5 models.py (short version)

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=450)
    url = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=450)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    last_update = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=_get_upload_image, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ("url", "user"),
        )

    def _get_upload_image(instance, filename):
        return "images/%s_%S" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)
```

Comment: Change the access of `_get_upload_image` from  a class method to a helper method (de-indent by one level), and It would work

Comment: I have already more functions in this class, this is app django-feedme and I want extend this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this through placing function on top of class

```
class Feed(models.Model):

    def _get_upload_image(instance, filename):
        return "images/%s_%S" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

    link = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=450)
    url = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=450)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    last_update = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=_get_upload_image, blank=True, null=True)
```